# How in CMake add aditional folders for headers to source code include path

Tags: cmake, include

Im have `INTERFACE` library `libA`, what include some headers, used by main project.

```
/- 
/ --- LibA
/ --- --- CMakeLists.txt
/ --- --- include/
/ --- --- --- my_lib_header.h
/ --- Project
/ --- --- CMakeLists.txt
/ --- --- main.c
```

```
LibA CMakeLists.txt

add_library(my_lib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(my_lib INTERFACE ./include)
```

```
Project CMakeLists.txt

add_executable(project main.c)
target_link_libraries(project INTERFACE my_lib)
```

I want to `my_lib` header files have additional directory in include path.

```
main.c

#include "myLib/my_lib_header.h"

int main()
{

}
```

The root of problem - im linked external library to my project. This library in most use cases have his own folder with inludes `#include <lib/lib_header.h>`. But in my case i have all headers in global scope `#include <lib_header.h>` and cant understand how it depends on CMake code.

Comment: "But in my case i have all headers in global scope `#include <lib_header.h>` and cant understand how it depends on CMake code." - With the command `target_include_directories(my_lib INTERFACE ./include)` you specify `LibA/include` as an **include directory**, so a compiler tries to resolve paths in `#include` directive **relative** to that directory. `#include <my_lib_header.h>` is resolved to the path `LibA/include/my_lib_header.h` because you actually have this file, but `#include <lib/my_lib_header.h>` is not resolved because it corresponds to absent file `LibA/include/lib/my_lib_header.h`.

Comment: Ok. Can you post this as answer?

Comment: Note that the properties of an `INTERFACE` lib are evaluated in the context of the target inheriting thost properties. For this reason the include dir shouldn't be relative, but absolute: `target_include_directories(my_lib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)`

Comment: @fabian as i see by result, it automatically make absolute path, when `target_include_directories()` evaluated.