# Include headers with same name but from different libraries using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, include

I have two (or more) libraries containing header files that have the same name (e.g., "point.h"). In my project(s), I need to use attributes from the classes defined in those headers in different contexts, but of course, is not possible to include the correct file in the common way, having the ambiguity of same name.

Many libraries solve this issue by "namespacing" their headers (e.g., "#include <rapidjson/document.h>"). I would like to do this. How can I configure CMake to achieve this? Is there a common (and possibly simple) way to do this?

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(GISManager LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
find_package(OSMManager REQUIRED) #First libray
find_package(GeoJSONParser REQUIRED) #Second library

set(GISManager_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(GISManager_H ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(Hdrs ${GISManager_H}/gismanager.h )
set(Srcs ${GISManager_SRC}/gismanager.cpp)

add_library(GISManager ${Hdrs} ${Srcs})
target_include_directories(GISManager PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${GISManager_H}/>
    ${OSMManager_INCLUDE_DIRS}/
    ${GeoJSONParser_INCLUDE_DIRS}/
)
target_link_libraries(GISManager ${OSMManager_LIBRARIES} ${GeoJSONParser_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(GISManager_Test ${Hdrs} ${Srcs} ${GISManager_SRC}/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(GISManager_Test PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${GISManager_H}/>
    ${OSMManager_INCLUDE_DIRS}/
    ${GeoJSONParser_INCLUDE_DIRS}/
)
target_link_libraries(GISManager_Test ${OSMManager_LIBRARIES} ${GeoJSONParser_LIBRARIES})

install(FILES  ${Hdrs}  DESTINATION include/GISManager-${version})
install(TARGETS GISManager
        DESTINATION lib/GISManager-${version}
        EXPORT GISManager-targets)
install(EXPORT GISManager-targets
        DESTINATION lib/GISManager-${version})

configure_file(
   ${GISManager_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg/gismanager-config.cmake.in
   ${GISManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/gismanager-config.cmake @ONLY)

configure_file(
   ${GISManager_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg/gismanager-config-version.cmake.in
   ${GISManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/gismanager-config-version.cmake @ONLY)

install(FILES ${GISManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/gismanager-config.cmake
         ${GISManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/gismanager-config-version.cmake
         DESTINATION lib/GISManager-${version})
```

The libraries are generated using the next two CMakeLists.txt files:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(GeoJSONParser LANGUAGES CXX)
set(version 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(GeoJSONParser_H ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(GeoJSONParser_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
find_path(RapidJSON_INCLUDE_DIRS rapidjson)


set(HDRS
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/object.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/featurecollection.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/feature.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/geometry.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/point.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/multipoint.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/linestring.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/multilinestring.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/polygon.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/multipolygon.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/geometrycollection.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/utils.h
    ${GeoJSONParser_H}/types.h
)
set(SRCS
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/featurecollection.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/feature.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/point.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/multipoint.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/linestring.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/multilinestring.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/polygon.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/multipolygon.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/geometrycollection.cpp
    ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/utils.cpp
)

add_library(GeoJSONParser ${HDRS} ${SRCS})
target_include_directories(GeoJSONParser PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${GeoJSONParser_H}/> ${RapidJSON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(GeoJSONParser_Test ${HDRS} ${SRCS} ${GeoJSONParser_SRC}/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(GeoJSONParser_Test PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${GeoJSONParser_H}/> ${RapidJSON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

install(FILES  ${HDRS}  DESTINATION include/GeoJSONParser-${version})
install(TARGETS GeoJSONParser
        DESTINATION lib/GeoJSONParser-${version}
        EXPORT GeoJSONParser-targets)
install(EXPORT GeoJSONParser-targets
        DESTINATION lib/GeoJSONParser-${version})

configure_file(
   ${GeoJSONParser_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg/geojsonparser-config.cmake.in
   ${GeoJSONParser_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/geojsonparser-config.cmake @ONLY)

configure_file(
   ${GeoJSONParser_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg/geojsonparser-config-version.cmake.in
   ${GeoJSONParser_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/geojsonparser-config-version.cmake @ONLY)

install(FILES ${GeoJSONParser_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/geojsonparser-config.cmake
         ${GeoJSONParser_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/geojsonparser-config-version.cmake
         DESTINATION lib/GeoJSONParser-${version})
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(OSMManager LANGUAGES CXX)
set(version 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(OSMManager_H ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(OSMManager_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
find_path(RapidJSON_INCLUDE_DIRS rapidjson)
find_package(PROJ)

set(HDRS
    ${OSMManager_H}/root.h
    ${OSMManager_H}/node.h
    ${OSMManager_H}/way.h
    ${OSMManager_H}/relation.h
    ${OSMManager_H}/coordinatesconverter.h
    ${OSMManager_H}/utils.h
    ${OSMManager_H}/types.h
    ${OSMManager_H}/tinyxml2.h
)
set(SRCS
    ${OSMManager_SRC}/root.cpp
    ${OSMManager_SRC}/node.cpp
    ${OSMManager_SRC}/way.cpp
    ${OSMManager_SRC}/relation.cpp
    ${OSMManager_SRC}/coordinatesconverter.cpp
    ${OSMManager_SRC}/tinyxml2.cpp
)

add_library(OSMManager ${HDRS} ${SRCS})
target_include_directories(OSMManager PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${OSMManager_H}/> ${RapidJSON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROJ_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(OSMManager ${PROJ_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(OSMManager_Test ${HDRS} ${SRCS} ${OSMManager_SRC}/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(OSMManager_Test PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${OSMManager_H}/> ${RapidJSON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROJ_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(OSMManager_Test ${PROJ_LIBRARIES})

install(FILES ${HDRS} DESTINATION include/OSMManager-${version})
install(TARGETS OSMManager
        DESTINATION lib/OSMManager-${version}
        EXPORT OSMManager-targets)
install(EXPORT OSMManager-targets
        DESTINATION lib/OSMManager-${version})

configure_file(
   ${OSMManager_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg/osmmanager-config.cmake.in
   ${OSMManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/osmmanager-config.cmake @ONLY)

configure_file(
   ${OSMManager_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg/osmmanager-config-version.cmake.in
   ${OSMManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/osmmanager-config-version.cmake @ONLY)

install(FILES ${OSMManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/osmmanager-config.cmake
         ${OSMManager_BINARY_DIR}/pkg/osmmanager-config-version.cmake
         DESTINATION lib/OSMManager-${version})
```

The files *library*-config.cmake.in have more or less the same structure in the two libraries, here is the one for GeoJSONParser:

```
# Compute installation prefix relative to this file.
get_filename_component(_dir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_prefix "${_dir}/../.." ABSOLUTE)

# Import the targets.
include("${_prefix}/lib/GeoJSONParser-@version@/GeoJSONParser-targets.cmake")

# Report other information.
set(GeoJSONParser_INCLUDE_DIRS "${_prefix}/include/GeoJSONParser-@version@/")

file(GLOB GeoJSONParser_LIBRARIES "${_prefix}/lib/GeoJSONParser-@version@/lib*")
```

As you can see above, the two libraries have both a "utils.h", including some functions that are specific to the library in question.

Comment: 90% of the code seems irrelevant to the question, which makes it a bit difficult to read. Anyway, "several libraries solve this issue by (adding the containing folder) - yes, this is the way. Just make sure that the overall path to your headers is something around `proj_root/libs/include/LIB_A/header.h`

Comment: I'm sorry for including irrelevant information, I wanted to make sure I included all the necessary and probably went too far in the process :D
I am not sure I have correctly understood the answer: are you saying I have to refer to the libs folder? Isn't it possible to refer to any other folder containing the headers provided that the folder has the correct name (e.g., supposing I have called "make install", obtaining /usr/local/include/OSMManager in an Ubuntu system)?

Comment: Yes yes, it was only example. Sure, if you have headers in `/usr/local/include/OSMManager` you only need to have `/usr/local/include` as your include directory, and then you can use the headers like `#include "OSMManager/header.h"`

Comment: Ok, it was simpler than I thought :D thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Don't show your actual code and config. Abstract away the contextul details to show the smalle representative example config/setup. That's how you provide long term value to the community (which is a big part of what SO is about)

Comment: Funnily, this question has a lot of similarities to [another question that was asked just one day before it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74867467/11107541) (but not enought to be a duplicate).

Comment: I see only one "point.h" in your "CMakeLists.txt" file. Where is the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Just make it so that the include directories passed to the compiler are directories that contain such an intermediate directory that does the namespacing that you want to have for the `#include` directives.

You'll want to make it so for both the source tree and the install tree.

If you'd like an answer with config code, please provide a minimal, respresentative example setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be two ways:
  I haven't tried the second method.

---

First method is that you may add same name header files by adding the folder name in `#include`.

Let's say that you have two "point.h" files in different folders:
  "include/two_dim/point.h" and "include/three_dim/point.h"

You may consider putting the folder name in your source code, CPP:

```
#include two_dim/point.h
#include three_dim/point.h
```

Here is an example of the portion of the "CMakeLists.txt"

```
set(project_name GISManager) 
project(${project_name})
set(includes include)
set(exec_sources src/main.cpp) 
add_executable( ${project_name} ${exec_sources} )
target_include_directories ( ${project_name} PUBLIC ${includes} )
```

---

Second way is using two "target_include_directories" lines.

Let's say that you have two "point.h" files in different folders, but parent folder name, "geo", is the same as well:
  "include/two_dim/geo/point.h" and "include/three_dim/geo/point.h"

You may consider putting the folder name in your source code, CPP:

```
#include geo/point.h
#include geo/point.h
```

Here is an example of the portion of the "CMakeLists.txt"

```
set(project_name GISManager) 
project(${project_name})
set(includes_two_dim include/two_dim)
set(includes_three_dim include/three_dim)
set(exec_sources src/main.cpp) 
add_executable( ${project_name} ${exec_sources} )
target_include_directories ( ${project_name} PUBLIC ${includes_two_dim} )
target_include_directories ( ${project_name} PUBLIC ${includes_three_dim} )
```